# Access Fantasy Premier League 2019/20 data through API

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, api

I am trying to pull fixtures data from Fantasy Premier League API. But i am stuck. I received string data instead of JSON data. It's been while since i used PHP, as i am more focused in JavaScript these days. Please guide me.

```
<?php
 $arrContextOptions=array(
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
        );
        $url = "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/fixtures/?event=1";
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
        // echo $response;

         $events  = json_encode($response, true);
         print_r($events);
         ?>
```

Variable $events gives me string instead array. It's because API is giving data in string format or i am doing something wrong.

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Do not switch SSL verification off. It is a big security issue.

Comment: I am using official laptop which has various firewalls. That is why i used it.

Comment: Firewalls have nothing to do with SSL Certificates in my opinion. Just download the up to date cert and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you confused between [json-encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json-decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php),

`json-encode`, the function you using take object and convert it to string - so having `$events` as string is the expected behavior.

`json-decode` on the other hand, take string and convrt it to object - so you should use that as:

```
$events  = json_decode($response, true);
```